# запустить бат файл в каждом каталоге

Tags: cmd

[image: вот тут и лежит батник который копирует батник во все эти папки]

вот тут и лежит батник, который копирует батник во все эти папки,
и мне нужно, что бы батник в каждой папке запустился и сделал что в нем написано

```
for /D %%a in ("C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\*.*") do xcopy /y /d "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\pere.bat" "%%a"
```

вот что выше это nazv.bat и он копирует pere.bat в каждую папку вот и мне надо как то запустить в каждой папке этот самый pere.bat

```
for %%i in (*.jpg) do for /L %%k in (1,1,10) do ren %%i %%k.jpg
```

то что выше это pere.bat он переименовывает все jpg по порядку вот и мне надо это сделать разом во всех папках, единственное до чего додумался как запихать этот батник в каждую папку но не получается его автоматически запустить, ещё было бы круто если бы он после того как отработает удалялся.

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: а зачем копировать? вроде как в этой вашей ms/windows, как и в любой полноценной операционной системе, тоже имеется свойство процесса "текущий каталог". разве им нельзя воспользоваться?

Comment: нельзя.  он форк-бомбу делает )))

Comment: *он копирует pere.bat в каждую папку вот и мне надо как то запустить в каждой папке этот самый pere.bat* А зафигом его копировать, если можно сразу запускать?

Comment: @Akina я был бы благодарен, если бы вы мне сказали как это сделать, я чуть подробнее расписал чего хочу добиться.